# Gtk::ComboBoxText select item with mouse on dropdown macOS Ventura 13.2.1 Gtkmm4

Tags: macos, user-interface, gtkmm, gtk4

I have added a simple ComboBoxText widget to my programm, but I am unable to select any of the drop-down options with my mouse by clicking on the drop-down. I can however use my keyboard arrows and enter button to change the selected option. What should I do in order for my button click to register and select a drop-down item?

examplewindow.cc

```
#include <list>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <soci.h>
#include <soci-sqlite3.h>
#include "examplewindow.h"

ExampleWindow::ExampleWindow()
: m_VBox(Gtk::Orientation::VERTICAL),
  m_Button_Quit("Quit"),
  m_Button_File("Choose File"),
  m_Button_Accept("Accept")
{
  set_title("Gtk::TreeView (ListStore) example");
  set_default_size(400, 200);

  m_VBox.set_margin(5);
  set_child(m_VBox);

  //Add the TreeView, inside a ScrolledWindow, with the button underneath:
  m_ScrolledWindow.set_child(m_TreeView);

  //Only show the scrollbars when they are necessary:
  m_ScrolledWindow.set_policy(Gtk::PolicyType::AUTOMATIC, Gtk::PolicyType::AUTOMATIC);
  m_ScrolledWindow.set_expand();

  m_ComboBoxText.append("Option 1");
  m_ComboBoxText.append("Option 2");
  m_ComboBoxText.append("Option 3");
  m_ComboBoxText.set_active_text("Option 1");

  m_ComboBoxText.signal_changed().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,
              &ExampleWindow::on_combo_changed) );

  m_VBox.append(m_ComboBoxText);
  m_VBox.append(m_ScrolledWindow);
  m_VBox.append(m_ButtonBox);

  m_ButtonBox.append(m_Button_File);
  m_ButtonBox.set_margin(5);
  m_Button_File.set_hexpand(true);
  m_Button_File.set_halign(Gtk::Align::BASELINE);
  m_Button_File.signal_clicked().connect( sigc::mem_fun(*this,
              &ExampleWindow::on_file_dialog) );

  m_ButtonBox.append(m_Entry);
  m_Entry.set_width_chars(20);
  m_Entry.set_hexpand(true);
  m_Entry.set_halign(Gtk::Align::FILL);
  m_Entry.signal_changed().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,
              &ExampleWindow::on_entry_changed));

  m_ButtonBox.append(m_Button_Accept);
  m_Button_Accept.set_hexpand(true);
  m_Button_Accept.set_halign(Gtk::Align::BASELINE);
  m_Button_Accept.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,
              &ExampleWindow::on_button_accept) );

  m_ButtonBox.append(m_Button_Quit);
  m_ButtonBox.set_margin(5);
  m_Button_Quit.set_hexpand(true);
  m_Button_Quit.set_halign(Gtk::Align::BASELINE);
  m_Button_Quit.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,
              &ExampleWindow::on_button_quit) );

}

ExampleWindow::~ExampleWindow()
{
}

void ExampleWindow::on_button_quit()
{
  set_visible(false);
}

void ExampleWindow::on_file_dialog()
{
  m_fileChooser = Gtk::FileChooserNative::create("Please choose a folder",  
                                                 *this,    
                                                 Gtk::FileChooser::Action::OPEN,
                                                 "Choose",
                                                 "Cancel");

  m_fileChooser->signal_response().connect(
            [this](int p_responseID)
            {
              this->on_browse_button_clicked(p_responseID);
            }
        );

  m_fileChooser->show();
}

void ExampleWindow::on_button_accept()
{
  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> content;

  std::string db_name = m_path;
    //std::remove(db_name.c_str());

  if (db_name.empty())
  {
    return;
  }

  std::cout << db_name << std::endl;

  soci::session sql(soci::sqlite3, db_name);

  soci::rowset<soci::row> rs = (sql.prepare << "SELECT * FROM users");

  // iteration through the resultset:
  int i = 0;
  for (soci::rowset<soci::row>::const_iterator it = rs.begin(); it != rs.end(); ++it)
  {

    soci::row const& row = *it;

    std::vector<std::string> row_content;

    for(std::size_t j = 0; j != row.size(); ++j) {

      const soci::column_properties & props = row.get_properties(j);

      switch(props.get_data_type())
      {
        case soci::dt_string:
            row_content.push_back(row.get<std::string>(j));
            break;
        case soci::dt_double:
            row_content.push_back(std::to_string(row.get<double>(j)));
            break;
        case soci::dt_integer:
            row_content.push_back(std::to_string(row.get<int>(j)));
            break;
        case soci::dt_long_long:
            row_content.push_back(std::to_string(row.get<long long>(j)));
            break;
        case soci::dt_unsigned_long_long:
            row_content.push_back(std::to_string(row.get<unsigned long long>(j)));
            break;
        case soci::dt_date:
            break;
        case soci::dt_xml:
            break;
        case soci::dt_blob:
            break;
      }
    }

    content.push_back(row_content);

    i++;
  }

  if (m_refTreeModel) {
    m_TreeView.remove_all_columns();
  }

  m_Columns = new ModelColumns(content.at(0).size());

  //Create the Tree model:
  m_refTreeModel = Gtk::ListStore::create(*m_Columns);
  m_TreeView.set_model(m_refTreeModel);
 
    for(int i=0;i<content.size();i++)
    {
    auto row = *(m_refTreeModel->append());
        for(int j=0;j<content[i].size();j++)
        {
      row[*(m_Columns->col_vect.at(j))] = content[i][j];
        }
    }

  for (int k = 0; k < content.at(0).size(); k++) {
      m_TreeView.append_column("Column " + std::to_string(k), *(m_Columns->col_vect.at(k)));
  }

}

void ExampleWindow::on_entry_changed()
{
  m_path = m_Entry.get_text();
}

void ExampleWindow::on_combo_changed()
{
  std::string m_ComboText= m_ComboBoxText.get_active_text();
  std::cout << "Hola" << std::endl;
  m_ComboBoxText.set_active_text(m_ComboText);
}

void ExampleWindow::on_browse_button_clicked(int p_responseID)
{
  switch(p_responseID)
  {
      case GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT:
      {
          m_path = m_fileChooser->get_file()->get_path();
          m_Entry.set_text(m_path);
          break;
      }
      case GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL:
      {
          std::cout << "Cancel clicked : " << p_responseID  << std::endl;
          break;
      } 
      default:
      {
          std::cout << "Unexpected button clicked: " << p_responseID << std::endl;
          break;
      }
  }
}
```

[image: ComboBoxText drop-down]

Could not select GTK::ComboBoxText drop-down item with mouse click, only with keyboard.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your case on my setup (Gtkmm 3.24.20 on Ubuntu) and everything works as expected. Did you try your code on another OS to see if you get the same behavior? This is what I would try first.

Comment: On another note: It is nice that you have added code to show the problem. However, the code snippet you have posted contains a lot of unrelated stuff (it looks like a dump of your real code), like SQL code and the like. Furthermore, some of it is missing. For example, the header for the window is not there. You should reduce the amount of code to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem. Otherwise people will not try it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!! I'll try to see if I can get my hands on another computer with more storage space and run the code on a different os!!!